# Apache Mountain Lion Not Working

Tags: apache, osx-mountain-lion, httpd.conf

I have searched the internet non-stop for three days to find a fix for my problem, but nothing is working.

My Apache is loaded, my httpd.conf file is default other than the PHP5 LoadModule which is now uncommented, and the permissions on all files are at least read allowed.

I have done a complete clean reinstall of Mountain Lion, only restoring my User account with Time Machine.

Here are a few important parts of my httpd.conf file (as they came default):

```
ServerRoot "/usr"

#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80

User _www
Group _www

#ServerName www.example.com:80

DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My **UserName.conf** file (**James.conf**):

```
<Directory "/Users/James/Sites/">          
    Options Indexes MultiViews     
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit          
    Order allow,deny          
    Allow from all     
</Directory>
```

Comment: Try this guide http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/02/start-apache-web-server-mac-os-x/

Comment: Dude, there is almost no link you can send me that I haven't followed.

Comment: Maybe try changing AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit to AllowOverride All (in James.conf). Also the file you are trying to open must be in the Home Directory inside the folder named Sites. Lets say you have a folder named PHP there with a index.php in it. To access that you would go to http://localhost/~James/PHP/index.php in your browser. This preference pane should let you toggle your server on/off - http://clickontyler.com/blog/2012/02/web-sharing-mountain-lion/

Comment: The change to James.conf does not work, and the preference pane is broken. Turning on Web Sharing does nothing other than change the state of the switch. The red light is still shown, and 'Web Sharing is OFF' is displayed regardless of the state of the UISwitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately after doing a completely clean reinstall of Mountain Lion I was still unable to successfully start Apache. I even downloaded the System Preferences Pane for Web Sharing from clickontyler.com/blog/2012/02/web-sharing-mountain-lion and this still did not work.

The only thing that did allow me to take advantage of an Apache server on my Macbook Pro was by downloading XAMPP from [here](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check this file

```
/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf*
```

I commented out the dummy vhosts

I also had made a typo in the httpd.conf and when i fixed that things started working